# How to record user actions in native mobile app?

Tags: javascript, java, kernel, adb

I am working on recording feature to get all tap,zoom,finch actions. I started with adb command but i am not able to filter because event list is different for each device. How can i get information of touch,swipe,zoom when user performed actions in mobile app. Please help me to start in JAVA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics tool for android.
It records the track of your user action.

Comment: Okay. I am developing new automation software. I want to automate the actions. User can play the recorded actions.

Comment: Then google analytics wont help. you need to write the code in such a way that it creates a execution pattern. And when it execute again then do the same thing on the app.

Comment: Your working process for all the app is  1. save the users action where the user tap or click on android. 2. clone the process (maybe impossible) from the matrix of action occurred.

Comment: yes exactly. 

1. save the users action where the user tap or click on android. 
2. clone the process (maybe impossible) from the matrix of action occurred